# String into a JavaScript array

Tags: javascript, arrays

How can I convert a string to a JavaScript array?

Look at the code:

```js
//string
[[104.403322,30.920255],[104.410703,30.897555],[104.402292,30.892353],[104.389846,30.891365]]
```

Is there any chance to convert such string into a JavaScript array?

I want:

```js
[
 [104.403322,30.920255],
 [104.410703,30.897555], 
 [104.402292,30.892353],
 [104.389846,30.891365]
]
```

Thank you!!

Comment: That was not a string.

Comment: I'm sorry,is object;

Comment: **I define it**

![](https://i.loli.net/2019/11/27/vLkzW1Ncjd5ADli.png)
![](https://i.loli.net/2019/11/27/EBcat8rQlCG7eVI.png)


**I got it.**

![](https://i.loli.net/2019/11/27/PWazjJq2Of5kury.png)
![](https://i.loli.net/2019/11/27/kaI7ohTtnYE5G9b.png)

Answer (score 2):

Yes, that's a JSON string. You can use the `JSON.parse` method, see below.

```js
const str = "[[104.403322,30.920255],[104.410703,30.897555],[104.402292,30.892353],[104.389846,30.891365]]";

console.log(JSON.parse(str));
```

Comment: I define it ，img=>https://i.loli.net/2019/11/27/vLkzW1Ncjd5ADli.png，https://i.loli.net/2019/11/27/EBcat8rQlCG7eVI.png； I got it， img=>https://i.loli.net/2019/11/27/PWazjJq2Of5kury.png，https://i.loli.net/2019/11/27/kaI7ohTtnYE5G9b.png